# Not receiving any inputs from mousePressed() and keyPressed()

Tags: html, dom, user-input, p5.js

The design of this interface is that (1) there is a rectangle; (2) Press left and right arrows should adjust its width; (3) Press up and down arrows should change its height; (4) Press MOUSE should change its color; (5) Press BUTTON should gradually increase its rotation speed.

So I basically recreated functions like `mousePressed()` and `KeyPressed()` from references provided by p5.js's official website. Yet I realized that the sketch will only draw once and receives no user inputs. I know there is a problem but what could be the reason?

```
let width; // Controlled by LEFT_ARROW and RIGHT_ARROW
let height; // Controlled by UP_ARROW and DOWN_ARROW
let color; // Controlled by MOUSE
let degree; // Controlled by BUTTON

function setup() 
{
    // Create title, subtitle and button
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    var title = createElement('h1', 'Use ARROW buttons to resize the rectangle.')
    var subtitle = createElement('h2', 'Click MOUSE to change the color.')
    var button = createButton('Press Me to rotate the rectangle.')
    title.position(windowWidth/2-310, windowHeight/3-100);
    subtitle.position(windowWidth/2-180, windowHeight/3);
    button.position(windowWidth/2-100, windowHeight*3/4);
    button.mousePressed(buttonPressed);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    angleMode (DEGREES);
}

function draw()
{
    background(200);
    translate(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
    width = 10;
    height = 10;
    color = 0;
    degree = 0;
    fill(color);
    rotate(degree);
    // Draw a rectangle, set to default
    rect(0, 20, width, height);  

}

// This should rotate the object
function buttonPressed()
{
    degree = degree + 10;
}

// This should change the color    
function mousePressed()
{
    color = random(255);
}

function keyPressed()
{
    // This should change the width, using left and right arrow
    if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW)
    {
        width = width - 10;
    }
    else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW)
    {
        width = width + 10;
    }

    // This should change the height, using up and down arrow
    if (keyCode === UP_ARROW)
    {
        height = height - 10;
    }
    else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW)
    {
        height = height + 10;
    }
}

function windowResized()
{
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple logic error in your code. Initialize width, height, color and degree in the `setup` function instead of in `draw` so that the updates in the handlers are not overwritten.

```js
let width; // Controlled by LEFT_ARROW and RIGHT_ARROW
let height; // Controlled by UP_ARROW and DOWN_ARROW
let color; // Controlled by MOUSE
let degree; // Controlled by BUTTON

function setup() 
{
    // Create title, subtitle and button
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    var title = createElement('h1', 'Use ARROW buttons to resize the rectangle.')
    var subtitle = createElement('h2', 'Click MOUSE to change the color.')
    var button = createButton('Press Me to rotate the rectangle.')
    title.position(windowWidth/2-310, windowHeight/3-100);
    subtitle.position(windowWidth/2-180, windowHeight/3);
    button.position(windowWidth/2-100, windowHeight*3/4);
    button.mousePressed(buttonPressed);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    angleMode (DEGREES);
    // initialize variables here
    width = 10;
    height = 10;
    color = 0;
    degree = 0;
}

function draw()
{
    background(200);
    translate(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
// don't overwrite the changes from the handlers
// instead move initialization to setup
//    width = 10;
//    height = 10;
//    color = 0;
//    degree = 0;
    fill(color);
    rotate(degree);
    // Draw a rectangle, set to default
    rect(0, 20, width, height);  

}

// This should rotate the object
function buttonPressed()
{
    degree = degree + 10;
}

// This should change the color    
function mousePressed()
{
    color = random(255);
}

function keyPressed()
{
    // This should change the width, using left and right arrow
    if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW)
    {
        width = width - 10;
    }
    else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW)
    {
        width = width + 10;
    }

    // This should change the height, using up and down arrow
    if (keyCode === UP_ARROW)
    {
        height = height - 10;
    }
    else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW)
    {
        height = height + 10;
    }
}

function windowResized()
{
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your question also mentions rotation speed. In the snippet the button click changes the degree variable. To get the rectangle to rotate at a speed you will need to add another variable which you can call speed. Then adjust speed in the button click handler and set degree = degree + speed in draw.

Comment: Another thing I notice is that you probably want the rectangle to rotate around its center. You can use translate to move to the center of the rectangle and then rotate. If you need help with rotation around the center ask another question.

Comment: This solves the problem. Thanks, Charlie! Yeah, the rotation was another issue, one that I didn't realize when posted this question. But I've managed to modify that part myself once I have the interactions implemented. Still, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not super experienced but I don’t see an .adEventlistner() this looks out for any input on the site.
Here is some code I used for the controls that I used in a recent course where I made a snake game. I used the key codes for the arrows (left arrow: 37, up arrow: 38, right arrow: 39, down arrow: 40)

```js
function control(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        direction = 1
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        direction = - width
    } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        direction = -1
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        direction = width
    }
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', control)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, though I believe `.addEventlistner()` is not a necessity for this specific purpose. It was all due to a simple logic error. Putting variables into draw() instead of setup() will solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks its always nice to learn from these kind of post and people who know more about the subject